# NodeJS Don't return before variable/json has changed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have here a piece of code:

```
TradeFunc.prototype.getOffer = function( callback ){
    var self = this;
    if ( this.offer )
        return callback ? callback( null, this.offer ) : null;

    var bot = this.getBot();
    if ( !bot )
        return console.log( '» Trade ' + colors.red('failed') + ' to get offer, bot not found!' ); 

    bot.offers.getOffer({
        tradeofferid: self.tradeofferid
    }, function( err, trade ) {        
        if ( !err && trade && trade.response && trade.response.offer ) {
            self.offer = trade.response.offer;
            return callback ? callback( null, trade.response.offer ) : null;
        } else { 
            self.getOfferRetry( callback );
        }
    });

};
```

So, `bot.offers.getOffer` gets the data needed, basically I want to add there `if` `self.offer.trade_offer_state` equals `9`, then it will get that `bot.offers.getOffer` again and it won't do that return. It will do it until the `trade_offer_state` is not `9`.

How could I do that, I have been trying, but I can't find a right solution for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just extend the `if` condition, which you already have, to:

```
if ( !err && trade && trade.response && trade.response.offer 
          && trade.response.offer.trade_offer_state !== 9 ) {
```